# How to call variable (Object)'s method in expression syntax? [Twig Templating]

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How to call a variable's method in expression syntax in twig tempting system.
see the example below

```
{{ myObj.someMethod() }} {# this print the output of this method #}
```

i don't want above code because its printing output of this method.
but i want this

```
{% myObj.someMethod() %}
```

but its is giving me error that

```
Unknown tag name "myObj" in "
{% myObj.someMethod() %}" at line 2
```

even with above error method is also being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In twig syntax `{{ some variable}}` will print the result in variable you need to set variable and then use where you want

```
{% set myvar = myObj.someMethod() %}  /* this will store the result returned from function */

{{ myvar }} /* this will print the result in myvar */
```

Comment: do i have to write two lines for this...... i just want to call a method.. no need to output

Comment: `{% %}` can be used to work around with value returned by function, and yes you need two line one to set variable and if you want to print  then `{{ }}` will be used

Comment: now i understand this is VIEW and so there is no need of calling a method for logic processing.. thats why i think twig don't have any thing like this...

Comment: Yes just treat it as view ,pass all data from controller but if you need some sort of loops ,if check these are provided in twig extension with some php functions work around is also provided